# What's wrong with this antlr grammar? wildcard problem?

Tags: antlr

the grammar is simple enough:

```
expression: signal logic_op right_op;
signal: .+?;
right_op: .+?;
logic_op: GT|GTE|LT|LTE|NOT|EQ;
GT: '>';
GTE: '>=';
LT: '<';
LTE: '<=';
NOT: 'NOT';
EQ: '=';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

but I tested it with 'a > b', it gives me this error:

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'b'
line 1:5 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'NOT', '=', WS}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no lexer rule that matches `a` and `b`. Add this:

```
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
```

And if your follow up question is "but `a` and `b` are matched by `.+?`, right?", then the answer is "no". Inside a parser rule (like `signal`) a `.` (dot) matches any token. Inside a lexer rule the `.` matches any character.

Comment: and then `signal: ID;` and `right_op: ID;` for parser rules, correct?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ideally, yes. But not strictly needed because ANTLR will match "any token" for `.+?`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Just learning ANTLR myself.

Comment: You're most welcome @HovercraftFullOfEels. Best of luck with ANTLR!